# jQuery AJAX Database Query and updating HTML List with results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

i got a little problem with searching my database and outputting the data.

This is my template. Don't mind the `$page->_()`. this is because of my framework. just think of phps `echo`

```
<?php
$movies = array();
if( isset($_POST['searchtext']) && isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==1 )
    $movies = Movie::getByTitle( $_POST['searchtext'] );
$list = '<ul id="results">'; 
if( isset( $movies ) && $movies!=null )
    foreach($movies as $movie)
         $list.= '<li>'.$movie->getTitle().'</li>';
else if( isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==1 )
    $list.='<li>No Results!</li>';
$list.= '</ul>';

if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==1){
    $json = array(
        'success' => true,
        'html' => $list
    );
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Content-type: text/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
    die();
}
$page->_(
'<section class="dialog-fixed small">',
    '<form id="search-form" method="post" action="#home">',
        '<fieldset>',
            '<input type="text" name="searchtext" />',
            '<input type="submit" name="moviesubmit" value="Search"/>',
        '</fieldset>',
    '</form>'
);
$page->_($list);
$page->_('</section>');
?>
```

`Movie::getByTitle` just does a `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%".$title."%' LIMIT 30"` query, creates for each result an Movie Object and return an array with the objects

My jQuery AJAX Request works like this:

```
var f0 = $('#search-form');
if( f0.length>0 ) {
    f0.each(function(){
        var f = $(this);
        $(this).submit(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: BASEURL+f.attr('action'),
                data: f.serialize()+'&ajax=1',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.success){
                        $('#results').replaceWith(data.html);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr,txt,err) {
                    alert(txt+' ('+err+')');
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now..the Database table i query has about 1.000.000 rows (movies)
It works very well if i search for "Forrest Gump" for example...But if i search for something with fewer Characters lets say "One" it doesnt return anything. I tried searching my Database inside of phpmyadmin for "One" and it returned about 15.000 results...okay i thought this could be too many for my script to handle so i put a `LIMIT 30` at the end of my database query as you can see..
doesnt work either. i dont get anything in return after searching for "One" not even a "No Result" as it should (actually it shouldnt but you know what i mean). My script just stops working. 
And if i searched for something like "One" i can't search anything after this. Not even "Forrest Gump" gives me any results. 
Really cant figure out where the problem is. My Firebug doesnt help me ;)

Any hints?

EDIT:
Ok i found out where my problem was. json_encode($json) didn't work. i didnt figure out the reason yet. This solution works: 
script.js:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: BASEURL+f.attr('action'),
                data: f.serialize()+'&ajax=1',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data!=''){
                        $('#results').replaceWith(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr,txt,err) {
                    alert(txt+' ('+err+')');
                }
            });
```

php template:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==1){
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-type: text/html');
echo utf8_encode($list);
die();
}
```

Comment: did you try the SAME query from phpmyadmin that your script executes? (with LIKE '%One%')

Comment: Unless your query is returning a HTML element with id `results`, then the `.replaceWith` is most likely your problem... (it replaces the entire element, meaning it's not there to be used the next time you search)

Comment: @Herohtar then it wouldnt work if i try searching for e.g. "Mission Impossible" after searching for "Forrest Gump". But it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..found the problem. Some of the Strings in my database weren't correctly UTF-8...json_encode() had trouble with this so in my php template i had to change `$list.= '<li>'.$movie->getTitle().'</li>';` to `$list.= '<li>'.utf8_encode($movie->getTitle()).'</li>';`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using fulltext search? If so MySQL has a minimum number of characters you have to provide it when doing the fulltext search otherwise it returns nothing. That would be my first guess.

This is configurable although I do not know how to do it off the top of my head. It is down for a good reason, as fulltext search is often means to search through huge huge strings so that if you gave it simply "one" it would return many many massive rows. If this is not how you are using it, then you could probably reduce the amount of characters, although this would also give your user more to look through.

Answer (score 0):

Index on the field you are searching.
A primary index would get you a non-duplicate content, or use full-text index.
Detail [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Ok primary wont work because there a many Movies with the same title, but i'll try full-text index.